# PHPMailer multiple recipients with external file

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to include a list of recipients to the phpMailer script but with no success. It just prints out the list but doesn't include it in the function.

The file has to be external because it is part of an automated script that runs for different scenarios for different recipients.

Any ideas?

recipients.php

```
$mail->AddAddress('blabla@xyc.com');
$mail->AddAddress('gaga@xyz.com');
```

phpMailer.php

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 


try {
  include('recipients.php');

  $mail->AddCC('zyx@cba.com');
  $mail->SetFrom('xyz@abc.com');
  $mail->Subject = 'Subject Line';
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
  $mail->MsgHTML($email_message);
  $mail->IsHTML(true);



  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK</p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to follow **phpMailer's** defined interface, I would suggest **Gautam3164's** method too.
As you can only add one email address per function call. 
**phpMailer** is not built for **mailing list purpose**.

Otherwise, I would hack into AddAnAddress method of phpMailer perhaps add your own "mass address loading" method.

```
private function AddAnAddress($kind, $address, $name = '') {
.....
}
```

Or use **other** library for sending emails to **multiple recipients**.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Let first try to get all the receiptents from the external file and save them in an array and then take a for loop for all receiptents and fire the mail function..It will be easier for you ever